# MySQL GROUP BY error in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql

On trying to convert MySQL query to MsSql query ends in trouble.

Error states that:

> Column 'books.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This code sucks.

```
SELECT * FROM books group by books.category_id
```

For reference
[sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ed19/22](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ed19/22)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: Show us some sample table data, and the expected result!

Comment: MySQL simply returns a random row and you will notice that every other DBMS will return a similar error message. You must decide *which* row to return. Welcome to the world of *real SQL* :)

Comment: Note that this is disable in MySQL 5.7 with removal of Non-Deterministic Group By

Comment: @jarlh Please use this as reference sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ed19/22

Comment: SQLfiddle doesn't answer...

Comment: @cerd: I like that MySQL is finally switching to Standard SQL, but I bet that most installations will switch back to the old behaviour *not to break existing code* :)

Comment: @jarlh Sqlfiddle take time to loads.. I'll create new one.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ed19/22

Comment: Just post some sample data, and the expected result.

Comment: Consider books table { id name category_id} { 1 A 1} { 2 B 1} { 3 C 2} I want to fetch by grouping the category_id

Answer (score 1):

The projection area for this SQL query needs to have an aggregate on a column other than the one you are using for group by.

```
select colA, MAX(colB)
from myTable
group by colA
```

As you can see, the projection contains colA on which the grouping has been done. The other column used in projection is used along with an aggregate function.

Try not to use * as it will ask you to perform an aggregate on all remaining columns other than books.category_id

Comment: Suppose consider 3 of books having same category_id let us say 2. How do you go with that..?

Comment: Depends what you want to achieve using groupby. When three books will have the same category_id, then you need to decide on whether you want to sum their price or you wish to show the count, or you wish to show the maximum price amongst the three. 

If you can explain your requirement here, then maybe we can help.

Comment: Consider

books table

{   id    name category_id}
{    1    A          1}
{    2    B          1}
{    3    C          2}

I want to fetch by grouping the category_id

Comment: Since you are not aggregating any records and just wnat to show category_id you can avoid using groupBy and instead use DISTINCT. But if you are adamant on using group by using 


SELECT category_id
  FROM Test
  group by category_id

Comment: It will result category_id as 1 and 2 But I want the book result as 2/3 based on category_id.. Correct if I'm wrong

Comment: Rishi, I guess I'm unable to understand the requirement here. What does 2/3 represent here?